# Logstash Doesn't Read Entire Line With File Input

Tags: filter, logstash

I'm using Logstash and I'm having troubles getting a rather simple configuration to work.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "C:/path/test-data/*.log"
    start_position => beginning
    type => "usage_data"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "usage_data" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "^\s*%{NUMBER:lineNumber}\s+%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date},(?<value1>[A-Za-z0-9+/]+),(?<value2>[A-Za-z0-9+/]+),(?<value3>[A-Za-z0-9+/]+),(?<value4>[^,]+),(?<value5>[^\r]*)" }
    }
  }

  if "_grokparsefailure" not in [tags] {
    drop { }
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I call Logstash like this:

```
SET LS_MAX_MEM=2g

DEL "%USERPROFILE%\.sincedb_*" 2> NUL
"C:\Program Files (x86)\logstash-1.4.1\bin\logstash.bat" agent -p "C:\path\\." -w 1 -f "logstash.conf"
```

The output:

```
←[33mUsing milestone 2 input plugin 'file'. This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/plugin-milestones {:level=>:w
arn}←[0m
{
       "message" => ",",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2014-11-20T09:16:08.591Z",
          "type" => "usage_data",
          "host" => "my-machine",
          "path" => "C:/path/test-data/monitor_20141116223000.log",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_grokparsefailure"
    ]
}
```

If I parse only `C:\path\test-data\monitor_20141116223000.log` all lines are read and there is no `grokparsefailure`. If I remove `C:\path\test-data\monitor_20141116223000.log` the same `grokparsefailure` pops up in another log-file:

```
{
       "message" => "atches in another context\r",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2014-11-20T09:14:04.779Z",
          "type" => "usage_data",
          "host" => "my-machine",
          "path" => "C:/path/test-data/monitor_20140829235900.log",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_grokparsefailure"
    ]
}
```

Especially the last output proves that Logstash doesn't read the entire line or attempts to interpret a newline where there is none. It always breaks at the same line at the same position.

Maybe I should add that the log-files contain `\n` as a line separator and I'm running Logstash on Windows. However, I'm not getting a whole lot of errors, just that one. And there are quite a lot of lines in there. They all appear properly when I remove the `if "_grokparsefailure" ...`.

I assume that there is some problem with buffering, but I have no clue how to make this work. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue running on Windows. Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround:

```
# diff -Nur /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.5.1/lib/filewatch/tail.rb.orig /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.5.1/lib/filewatch/tail.rb
--- /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.5.1/lib/filewatch/tail.rb.orig       2015-02-25 10:46:06.916321816 +0700
+++ /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.5.1/lib/filewatch/tail.rb    2015-02-12 18:39:34.943833909 +0700
@@ -86,7 +86,9 @@
           _read_file(path, &block)
           @files[path].close
           @files.delete(path)
-          @statcache.delete(path)
+          #@statcache.delete(path)
+          inode = @statcache.delete(path)
+          @sincedb[inode] = 0
         else
           @logger.warn("unknown event type #{event} for #{path}")
         end
```

Comment: Well, thanks, but have you committed this to their source, too? It would be nice to have this in an official version.